# Critical points of a function

Tags: calculus

If you have a 2 variable function $f(x,y)$ and it has $(0,y)$ as a critical point where y is a variable then how do we know it is maxima or minima or saddle point? 
For example $$f(x,y)=x^2ye^{-x^2-y^2}?$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to find Hessian of your function, which is nothing but the matrix of second partial derivatives with respect to each variable. In your case
$$
H(x, y) = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y^2}
\end{array}
\right]
$$
If it is positive definite at critical point – it's local minimum, if negative definite then local maximum, if the sign is indefinite then it's a saddle point.

Comment: Note that if the Hessian is singular, this test is inconclusive.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: i am getting singular hessian,so what should I do next?